# Not able to deploy node.js + react.js app to Heroku due to wrong build script

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

I am running an express server which is hosting the react frontend at "/" and the api at "/api". It works on my local machine, but the build script fails when deploying to heroku:

this is my build script:

```
    "build": "npm install && npm i -g pm2 && cd client/ && npm install && npm run build && cd .. && pm2 start ./bin/www"
```

as you can see, first it installs npm modules for the express server, then pm2 which will run the express server, then it goes inside "client" folder which is the react app, and then installs node modules, builds the react app and generates the "dist" folder, and finally starts the express server.

it completes all steps in heroku cli until "cd.." with this error:

```
remote: sh: 1: cd..: not found
```

EDIT:
i changed "pm2" to "node" , and the website is working. so pm2 is not supported in heroku?

Comment: you need a buildpack to deploy a React app on Heroku. For instance, if you used create-react-app you can use the 'https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack' buildpack. Just enter that URL on the settings tab.

Comment: i deployed the react app(served by express) previously without the backend server with similar script, and it was working fine in heroku, but when i added the backend server, it is not working